# Converting Time into Numeric in R

Tags: r, time, type-conversion, numeric

I am working on a small project in R regarding sports modeling. It is a multinomial regression model to predict outcomes of hockey games. I have learned how to convert the Time On Ice column in my data frame into a numeric vector using the following function.

`AminPerGame <- AGoalies$TOI

```
sapply(strsplit(AminPerGame,":"),
       function(x) {
          x <- as.numeric(x)
         x[1]+x[2]/60
        }
  )`
```

I am looking to use an if statement, to convert the result of a win to an overtime if the game goes past 60 minutes. 3 is a win, 2 is an overtime.

```
`if ((AminPerGame>60) & (AGoalies$DEC == 3) )
{AGoalies$DEC == 2} `
```

I continue to get this error message

`Warning message:
In if ((AminPerGame > 60) & (AGoalies$DEC == 3)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.`

Any advice on how to get this if statement to convert the the result correctly?

Comment: You may need `ifelse` instead of `if` as the length is greater than 1

Comment: Replace your entire if statement and just use AGoalies$DEC[ AminPerGame>60 & AGoalies$Dec==3 ] <- 2